# Elaboração de gráfico

Tags: microsoft-excel

Boa noite. Vocês saberiam como monta o gráfico da figura abaixo, sendo que no gráfico os números 1, 2 .... deveriam pegar as 3 colunas ao lado, ficando algo do tipo: 1 1 de 10; 10%    observando que as colunas que não tem dados são simplesmente ignoradas. Preferencialmente que as barras do gráfico tenha cores diferentes para melhor entendimento do utilizador e que mantenha a mesma ordem das mercadorias. Essa ajuda pode ser por VBA ou por Excel simplesmente.

[image: Exemplo]

Comment: É só ordenar os dados da tabela antes de criar o gráfico, ordenando pela coluna `%`, do menor para o maior. Uma dica, quando perguntar algo, cole os dados no seu post, ao invés de colar como imagem, p/ evitar que nós tenhamos que recriar a tabela.

Comment: Na verdade  dot.Py, os dados devem ser ordenados pelas mercadorias. na tabela:  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8 e 9 no gráfico deve seguir esta mesma ordem (igual na imagem). Note que as mercadorias 6, 7, 10, 11 e 12 (que não "existem" na tabela, foram ignoradas no gráfico). E no gráfico, no lugar dos números deveria aparecer uma especie de concatenação dos dados das 3 colunas, ex: ao lado da barra de nº 1 do gráfico deveria aparecer algo do tipo: 1; 1 de 10; 10% (o mesmo para as demais barras)